# How to embed two ICC profiles in an image?

Tags: color-management, color-correction, icc-profile

Current task requires to embed input ICC profile as well as output (display) ICC profile such as Adobe RGB in an image. I tried to find a way to do this, for example, with **exiftool** in vain because the tool seemed to allow embedding single ICC profile.

Am I missing something or are we restricted to embed a single ICC profile per image?

Comment: Adobe RGB is not a display profile. A display profile will start with the name of your display [monitor] manufacturer... Dell, Apple, Samsung etc... & will be of zero value to anyone else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about image file formats with no particular relevance to photography.

Comment: @mattdm I totally disagree. I think both TIFF and ICC profiles are entirely relevant to digital photography today

Comment: They can be, but I bet they aren't for the use case here. If the question can be updated to clarify the relevance, that's fine with me.

Comment: @mattdm I am not actually interested in a specific image format such as TIFF. Accordingly I edited my post.

Comment: @mattdm The question is at least as relevant to photography as a question concerning copyright.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't have your dictionary and I know Adobe RGB is a color space, but when Adobe RGB ICC profile is embedded, Profile Class tag has "display device profile."

Comment: @benrudgers Some of the copyright questions are far afield. Some of them are of direct relevance to the practice of photography as a hobby or business.

Comment: @Paul What _are_ you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, there's no reason to embed more than more one profile. With an input image, you embed the input profile, so that your colour management system can work out what colours the numbers in the input data means.

No reason to embed a monitor or output profile - they're nothing to do with the image data, and if you move the image to a different system, you'd need to use a different monitor profile for viewing, or a different output profile for printing to a different printer or paper type.

Normally, the monitor profile is associated with the system you're viewing the image on - and you'd use that profile for all images you wanted to view on that monitor. (The monitor profile lets the colour management software figure out what values to send to the monitor to get a particular colour).

Similarly, the output profile lets the colour management software work out what ink values to send to the printer to get a particular colour. That varies with printer, ink, media and printer settings. Again, this is usually set by the printing software. If you're producing something like a CMYK file for conventional printing, then you might embed the output profile in the CMYK image. In this case, the colour management software could use the reverse cubes in profile to work out what colour the CMYK values in this file mean (for example, if you wanted to output the file on a different output device, where you'd need to go originalCMYK->colours->newCMYK using a different output profile).

Comment: I kind of agree with your stance, but sometimes a printing shop requires an image to embed an output ICC profile (e.g., sRGB or Adobe RGB) so their printer would know in which color space it need to output. I found that most of scanners embed sRGB ICC profile even if it was ICC-profiled with an input ICC profile. That was the reason for my question. Anyway, an embedded ICC profile per image seems to be true, Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that embedding the sRGB or AdobeRGB is effectively using that as an input profile for the print shop (ie. the numbers mean these colours), rather than an output one. With the scanners, most probably write the file as sRGB to keep things simple for basic users not using colour management; in that case, if you have the input ICC profile it might make sense to replace the original sRGB embedded profile with your generated ICC input profile - but if the scanner is trying to produce sRGB, the two should be very close anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried learning about colour management and icc profiles but only really understand the basics. I have created some profiles for displays and printers.

When creating a printer profile with [argyll - colprof](https://www.argyllcms.com/doc/colprof.html) for a specific printer / paper combination you can specify a source profile for the image to have before conversion. This handles the perceptual and saturation intent gamut mapping from the working colour space ie sRGB.icc to the printer space.

Is this what you are attempting? If so the argyll cms documentation will give more help than I can!